# Linked word squares

Tags: word, word-square

The following are clues to 18 six-letter words that must be filled into the following three linked [word squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square).

The clues are in no particular order, but just for fun, I tried to arrange them to tell a little story (which has no relevance to the puzzle's solution).

Overlapping portions of each square will obviously share the same letters.

[image]

- [image]
- Buyer and seller
- Acknowledge
- I
- Dissent
- Plagiarized
- Mocked
- Last
- Evil
- Plan
- Instructions
- Venerate
- Chamber
- Military instruments
- Deathly
- Word with *fire* or *search*
- Ball-drops
- Lands

Comment: Do plural form clues yield plural form answers? Same tense etc?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes.  The clues are in the style of a crossword like the New York Times crossword, and generally follow the same conventions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The eighteen words are (in the same order as in the question):

> `PRINCE`     (the artist later known as) Symbol
>  `DEALER`     Buyer and seller
>  `CREDIT`     Acknowledge
>  `IODINE`     (the chemical element whose symbol is) I
>  `UNREST`     Dissent
>  `STOLEN`     Plagiarized
>  `TEASED`     Mocked
>  `ENDURE`     Last
>  `SINFUL`     Evil
>  `AGENDA`     Plan
>  `RECIPE`     Instructions
>  `ESTEEM`     Venerate
>  `GROTTO`     Chamber
>  `BUGLES`     Military instruments
>  `LETHAL`     Deathly
>  `ENGINE`     Word with fire or search
>  `ERRORS`     Ball-drops (in Baseball, I believe)
>  `ESTATE`     Lands

This gives the following grid:

> `B U G L E S`
>  `U N R E S T`
>  `G R O T T O`
>  `L E T H A L`
>  `E S T A T E A S E D`
>  `S T O L E N G I N E`
>          `A G E N D A`
>          `S I N F U L`
>          `E N D U R E C I P E`
>          `D E A L E R R O R S`
>                  `C R E D I T`
>                  `I O D I N E`
>                  `P R I N C E`
>                  `E S T E E M`

Comment: "Ball-drops" could also be figurative, as in, "I dropped the ball on that one."

Comment: Amazing work, even with many of these, and many other options, I could not fit things together, I was going to write code to do it... (I would have thought lethal was deadly not deathly - I was thinking grisly, pallid, sallow, peaked etc...)

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Thanks! To be frank, I did write a program and fed it as many guesses as I could find just to get a start. I had pallid, sickly and so on for deadly, too. I was pretty sure that it had to be TAFKAP or symbol instead of Prince; I had cavern and cavity, but not grotto; trader instead of dealer; copied and lifted instead of the (rather obvious) stolen. I didn't get unrest, estate and errors until very late. I got bugles and iodine from the outset, but coudn't go anywhere with them. So, yeah, it was quite tough, but fun.